# How can I display multiple TableViews from a Json File in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uitableview, swift3

What I want to do is to display my information from a Json file into my TableView on Xcode(Swift). Here is an example for I want to to:

I want to retrieve my json data from countries, cities and some aditional information from cities. In the first screen I want to display the name of the countries in a TableView:

- Brazil
- Germany
- France
- USA
- Argentina
- etc...

Then, when I clic in a cell of one country (USA for example) I want to open a new TableView that contains all the states (or cities) from USA. So I clic on USA and I have the following information in the second screen:

- Florida
- New York
- California
- Nevada
- etc...

And finally when I clic in some state (or city), for example in New York I want to display some aditional information from the state I have selected (New York). So in the third screen I have:

"New York is an awesome city...etc"

I want to navegate from one tableview to another, so I don´t know how to add the "back" button on the top of the screen, for each tableview. The countries and the city i want to display in different cells, so I can clic on them and display the information.

Here is my json example:

```
[
    {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "city": [
            "Sao Paulo",
            "Rio de Janeiro"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Germany",
        "city": [
            "Berlin",
            "Frankfurt"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "city": [
            "Paris",
            "Marselle"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "city": [
            "Florida",
            "New York",
            "California",
            "Nevada"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Argentina",
        "city": [
            "Buenos Aires",
            "Mendoza",
            "La Plata"
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "England",
        "city": [
            "London",
            "Manchester",
            "Liverpool"
        ]
    }
]
```

Please can anybody help me to do this? How can I do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw: your json example is not valid json. The value for the key 'city' should be an array

Comment: What do you mean with "should be an array"? What would be the right expression for my Json example?

Comment: See RamenChef's edit

Comment: I got it Roel. This is the correct way to show mi cities:  "city": [
            "Florida",
            "New York",
            "California",
            "Nevada"
        ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty so simple, and most of the work is done by iOS and Xcode, you won't do so much work.

You need to get some know how in these topics: `UITableView`, `UINavigationController` and `Storyboards`.

You can follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) tutorial and you will find that it's a very easy task.

Here's the steps:

1. First of all, you need to design the app UI in a storyboard. You will create a scene view for the Countries screen, and another one for the Cities, and another one for the Cities Details screen.
2. Embed the first screen in `UINavigationController`, so that you get all the navigation stuff for free.
3. Show the countries data in Countries screen table view.
4. Make a segue from the Countries table view to Cities screen. So that when a country is selected, its cities is shown in the cities screen.
5. Pass the selected country object to the Cities screen using the method `prepareForSegue` (described in the tutorial I mentioned above).
6. Show the list of cities in the cities screen.
7. Do the same when navigating from Cities screen Cities Details screen.

Please read the tutorial first, then you will understand very well the steps I mentioned. It's pretty simple task that take around 1 hour to do.

Comment: Helo Minas, thank you for your time and for your answer. But how can I do that with a Json file? Is there another tutorial to follow that explains how to parse Json file into Swift? Just like I'm trying to do?

Comment: Parsing JSON is so simpler than you think. Check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial) tutorial. It's so easy using `NSJSONSerialization`. If you need further help, please tell me.

Comment: I think I'm a little lost. If you could help me with my app I would greatly appreciate it. Is there any mail, skype or whatever where I can write to you? Thanks a lot Minas!

Comment: Sure i'll be glad to help. You can reach me on twitter @minaskamel

Comment: Hi Minas, I have written you in twitter, but you haven´t replied me. So could you please give an email, so I can share my project with, and you can help me please! Thank you so much

Comment: sure, i replied you there... sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view data source methods are designed for this use case:

Use a stored `NSIndexPath *selected` to track the ui state in didSelectRow

Add an if statment to your data source methods, `if (selected)` to cellForRow and numberOfRows

In the `selected == nil` logic branch, `return dict.keys.count` for number of rows and return `dict.keys[indexPath.row][@"country"]` as the title for your row

In the `selected != nil` branch, `return dict[dict.keys[selected.row][@"cities"].keys.count` for number of rows and return `dict[dict.keys[selected.row]][@"cities"][indexPath.row]` as the title for your row